# Create cookie with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cookies, setcookie, angular-cookies

I tried to use the code below to set cookies:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http','$cookies', function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {

    $scope.setMyCookie = function () {
        $cookies.put('Mykey', 'MyValue');    
    };
    $scope.setMyCookie();
}]);
```

I updated to version 1.3.14 of angular cookies, I know there is a breaking change, but how should I write the above code now ?

Running the above code I get this error : `Error: $cookies.put is not a function`

---

UPDATE : 
I have to do this in 2 files:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

}]);

angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']).controller('cookiesExample', ['$cookies', function ($cookies) {
    // Retrieving a cookie
    var favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
    // Setting a cookie
    $cookies.myFavorite = 'oatmeal';
}]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happends via setting the `$cookies` variable:

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.myFavorite = 'oatmeal';
}]);
```

Your version:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http','$cookies', function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {

  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.myFavorite = 'oatmeal';
}]);
```

[Source](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

---

**NOTE:**
Remember to include `<script src="angular-cookies.js">` in your html.

Comment: well when I do this my page is absolutely not loaded

Comment: Edited just for you.. ;)

Comment: Of course the 'angular-cookies.js' is included. I tried your code, just change the controller name and the module name. The page is not loaded anymore

Comment: check for minior errors missing ; or others. You can use this tool : https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/

Answer (score 4):

You must inject `ngCookies` in your module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing `ngcookies` in your module

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])
```